# Installing a package (e.g. git) without internet access on SLES

Tags: linux, installation, git, sles

I am trying to install git on a SUSE linux server that, to all intents and purposes, doesn't have internet access.  It would appear that I also need to install some dependencies for git.

Is there a straightforward way of creating a package that contains git along with all its dependencies on another machine that I can the copy over to this server to install from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download git.tar.gz unpack-configure-compile

- Git is reasonably self-sufficient, but does depend on a few external
  programs and libraries.  Git can be used without most of them by adding
  the approriate "NO_=YesPlease" to the make command line or
  config.mak file.

  - "zlib", the compression library. Git won't build without it.
  - "ssh" is used to push and pull over the net.
  - A POSIX-compliant shell is required to run many scripts needed
    for everyday use (e.g. "bisect", "pull").
  - "Perl" version 5.8 or later is needed to use some of the
    features (e.g. preparing a partial commit using "git add -i/-p",
    interacting with svn repositories with "git svn").  If you can
    live without these, use NO_PERL.
  - "openssl" library is used by git-imap-send to use IMAP over SSL.
    If you don't need it, use NO_OPENSSL.

    By default, git uses OpenSSL for SHA1 but it will use it's own
    library (inspired by Mozilla's) with either NO_OPENSSL or
    BLK_SHA1.  Also included is a version optimized for PowerPC
    (PPC_SHA1).
  - "libcurl" library is used by git-http-fetch and git-fetch.  You
    might also want the "curl" executable for debugging purposes.
    If you do not use http:// or https:// repositories, you do not
    have to have them (use NO_CURL).
  - "expat" library; git-http-push uses it for remote lock
    management over DAV.  Similar to "curl" above, this is optional
    (with NO_EXPAT).
  - "wish", the Tcl/Tk windowing shell is used in gitk to show the
    history graphically, and in git-gui.  If you don't want gitk or
    git-gui, you can use NO_TCLTK.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the Steps I followed to install Git without internet access on the system

1. Download the desired tarball from below link, on your PC/Laptop https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/
   I used the Git-2.8, as the customer requirement was to have version >= Git-2.74
2. Connect to remote Linux system (via winscp or nay other remote connectivity tool). And Place/Move the downloaded git-XXXXXX.tar.gz file on desired location on the linux system where you want to install ‘git’.
   I placed it in Directory: `/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/`
3. From command prompt go to the directory where you placed the above file and run below command to untar the package `tar -xvzf git-2.8.0.tar.gz`
   CD into the directory that is newly created because of untar command above. `cd git-2.8.0/`
4. Verify that all the needed files and directories have been uncompressed into the above folder `ls -ltr`
5. Set the Path and Prefix variables with commands below.

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0/usr/bin

   PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0

   export PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0

   make prefix=/usr/local/git all

   echo $CC
   ```
6. Run Below command to check the preinstall configuration checks 
   `./configure`
7. Run Below command to install.
   `make install`
8. Now see it work with below command
   `git --version`

Answer (score 0):

#### Offline Install git on SLES 12 SP2  using SDK ISO

If you do not have direct access to the remote/online SLES zypper repositories, you can add ***SDK*** ISO as repository. Some packages are available in this ISO.

1) Download **SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso** from https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=g3e7P21X6Lw~ (It requires sign-up). You can also find your desired ISO sdk at https://download.suse.com

2) Copy & transfer downloaded file to the SLES machine. (here we transfer it to /temp/SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso)

3) Add ISO as Zypper repository

`zypper ar iso:/?iso=/temp/SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso sdk_dvd`

4) install git

`zypper install git-core`